# Session taking page back to login?

Tags: php, session

I am trying to access other pages only after I login. The Problem is when I submit data to the database to refresh pag2.php, and it takes me back to the login page which I do not want.

How can I fix this problem? This is my logic:

```
 pages.php

<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['log'])){
    header("location:login_page_crm.php");
 }

?>
```

Comment: How could we know from this one block of code - presumably the session is not set - welcome to programming 101 - the program does precicley what you tell it to

Comment: `exit()` after header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like jameson2012 told on comment, with this part of the code we cant see anything else.
But most likely, your `if(!isset($_SESSION['log'])){...}` is not set.
Try to check if your session is set. After you do that (and the page exists) you should be re-directed to `login_page_crm.php`.
or you could do a little debug - show another location after your if !
IF true => show login_page_crm.php else another page.php